# Get the id of maximum amount values in a associative array

Tags: php

I have an array in this format:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 117
            [name] => Apple
            [amount] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 188
            [name] => Orange
            [count] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 189
            [name] => Grapes
            [amount] => 7000
        )

)
```

I'm trying to get the id of max amount from the associative array.
how can i perform this?

i'm expecting the result

```
Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 189
                [name] => Grapes
                [amount] => 7000
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: where are the codes?

Comment: What if two entries have the same `amount`?

Comment: @kmoser i want both the ids

Comment: Then you have to sort the array on the amount value, then filter the result to only entries with the top amount.

Comment: @deceze grate! thanks!

Comment: You can get max amount (including duplicates) with this line $result = array_filter($yourArr, function($arr) use($yourArr) { return $arr['amount'] === max(array_column($yourArr, 'amount')); });

Comment: @kopz solved with your single line of code. thanks bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simplest to just initialise a "maxkey" value with `0` and then iterate over the array, replacing the key when you find a value with a higher `amount`:

```
$maxkey = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['amount'] > $data[$maxkey]['amount']) {
        $maxkey = $key;
    }
}
print_r($maxkey);
print_r($data[$maxkey]);
```

Output:

```
2
Array
(
    [id] => 189
    [name] => Grapes
    [amount] => 7000
)
```